# CIsco ASA 5505 have to change IP address of Server due to restructure

Tags: cisco, ipv4, cisco-asa, nat

I just went through and restructured my IP pool on `vlan 1`.  My issue is that my Windows VPN Server is now `10.1.10.11` instead of `10.1.10.122`.  I statically assigned the Windows server outside of my IP pool so that it would remain static.  How do I accomplish this IP address change in the ASA?  I've tried changing the object IP in the ASDM, no avail...  I am unsure what is the next step to take.  Here is my `show run`:

```
object-group network PPTP-server
object-group network hst-10.1.10.122  <-- THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO CHANGE
 description VPN-Server
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1
 network-object 10.xx.xx.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.xx.xx.0 255.255.255.0
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any interface outside eq pptp 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit icmp any any
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's actually just the name/identifier for that object. The object in question actually has no host address associated with it.

If you want to add to that existing object, then type:

```
config t
object-group network hst-10.1.10.122
 network-object 10.1.10.11 255.255.255.255
```

if you want to rename the object and add the host to it, do:

```
config t
no object-group network hst-10.1.10.122 ! This deletes the object
object-group network [desired name]
 network-object 10.1.10.11 255.255.255.255
```

A word of warning would be to make sure that object isn't being referred to anywhere else in the config. If it is, make sure to replace all instances with your new object if necessary.

Comment: ASA won't let you remove object-groups that are referenced by other parts of the configuration. OP will need to take the opposite approach to rename it; create the new object-group first, replace the old with the new wherever the old appears in the config, and then remove the old one.